# Which type of visa I should apply for to visit USA as job applicant?

Tags: visas, usa, work

I'm a Russian citizen and have been invited to the interview to United States and plan to go there on a two-day trip.
The question is - does anybody know which exactly type of visa I should apply for.

The list of visa categories [is big](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ru/ru-niv-visatypeinfo.asp#overview) and confuses me a little.

I've tried to call them (nobody takes up the phone), I guess I should visit them, but nevertheless it would be nice to know this beforehand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need a work visa, an H1-B.

Comment: @hippietrail - you are mistaken, I'm afraid, H-1B is or temporarily employment, not for 2 days visit ) I guess it is B1 i'm looking for.

Comment: @yourpersonalroo I recommend editing your question to make it clear that you're looking for a visa for the short trip you'll make to interview - upon first reading, I thought you were asking what type of visa you need in order to work in the US if you get the job. (The part about this being a 2-day trip is important, too.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [link](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ru/ru-niv-visatypeinfo.asp#overview) in your question, you do seem to [fit the requirements](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/ru/ru-niv-typeb1b2.asp) of a B-1 visa:

> If you apply for a B-1/B-2 visa, you must demonstrate to a consular
>   officer that you qualify for a U.S. visa in accordance with the U.S.
>   Immigration and Nationality Act (INA). Section 214(b) of the INA
>   presumes that every B-1/B-2 applicant is an intending immigrant. You
>   must overcome this legal presumption by showing:
>
> - That the purpose of your trip to the United States is for a
>     temporary visit, such as business, pleasure, or medical treatment
> - That you plan to remain in the United States for a specific, limited
>     period of time
> - Evidence of funds to cover your expenses while in the United States
> - That you have a residence outside the United States, as well as
>     other binding social or economic ties, that will ensure your return
>     abroad at the end of your visit

You may need a letter from the company that you are interviewing with, stating that they have invited you to their office for a professional matter. You will also (per the second item on the list above) be required to show your return ticket to Russia to prove that your stay in the US is specific and limited.

I suggest talking to whoever scheduled your interview to see if they have experience with international candidates (many companies can help their job candidates figure out what the necessary paperwork is), and keep trying to get in touch with the US embassy near you. It seems pretty clear that B-1 is the type of visa you need, but it's always best to make sure with the US government directly.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly B1/B2! I've had friends visiting US interviews who were getting B1/B2.